# Google Spreadsheet. How can I paint the background of empty cells between two numbers?

Tags: google-sheets

I have columns with months, for example in column February number 10, in column March number 20, then in column August number 10 and in column September number 20.
How to automatically fill the background in empty cells from February 10 to March 20 and from August 10 to September 20?

Comment: of course have  )

Comment: screen http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/01/15/0010/1659/710267/67/4ad566315e.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Select D:AA and use a CF formula rule of this kind:

```
=and(isblank(D1),isodd(COUNT(D1:AA1)))
```